# Struts2 Validation Messages do not show

Tags: java, struts2, validation

I have a strange issue down here. My struts2 `addFieldError(fieldName,ErrorMessage)` IS NOT showing the error on my jsp

also I AM extending `ActionSupport` , and in my Struts.xml I DO NOT have my theme set to simple.

My ActionListener is

```
package pebsms.actionBeans.UserActions;

import pebsms.business.UserBusiness.Impls.UserBusinessImpl;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    UserBusinessImpl userBusiness;

    public String userPassword;
    public String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

.   public String execute()
    {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void validate()
    {
        if (getUserPassword().length() <= 0)
            addFieldError(userPassword, "Enter Password");
        if (getUserName().length() <= 0)
            addFieldError(userName, "Enter UserName");
        if (!userBusiness.authenticateUser(userName, userPassword))
            addActionError("User authentication failed");**
    }
}
```

My Struts.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default" >
        <action name="Login" >
            <result>/pages/LoginScreen/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="LoginAction" class="userAction">
                    <result name="input">/pages/LoginScreen/Login.jsp</result>
            </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

`addFieldError` doesn't come up with the error messages on my jsp like it should automatically, even though the method is called inside the validate().

Comment: Have you included the error tag in your jsp?

Comment: So `"     "` (all spaces) is a valid user name? Also, you don't need to implement your own `execute()` if it doesn't do anything. Also not convinced it's worth doing validation manually when it's handled more easily via annotations (or XML I suppose).

Comment: Have you declared  <s:fielderror /> in jsp?

Comment: @tito No I have not included in the errortag , it does display the error if i do put the tag. But according to my understanding , the framework is supposedly to automatically inject the error. 

So I just wanted to know why is this automatic error display not working.

Comment: @DaveNewton I just put out a abstract version of the thing I am working on so yes it wont sound convincing. This action WOULD in future do a lot. 

Please do shed light on how to perform the validation through annotations ? I mean post a link etc. Thanks a barrel Dave

Comment: framework will inject the errors automatically but it cannot display it unless you include the error tag. [Take a look here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/FieldError.html)

Comment: @anu . I actually was going through Struts2 in action by manning publications. It clearly pastes this code there

<html>

 <head>
    <title>Portfolio Registration</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h4>Complete and submit the form to create your own portfolio.</h4> 
  <s:form action="Register">
       <s:textfield name="username" label="Username"/>
       <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
       <s:textfield name="portfolioName" label="Enter a name for your portfolio"/>   
     <s:submit/>
  </s:form> 
   
  
 </body>
 
</html>

Comment: this jsp's corresponding action , has a validate method , when it fires , we can see the messages in the jsp above. As you may have noticed it doesn't have a s:fielderror

Thanks anyways bro

Answer (score 0):

your addFieldError method is incorrect.  Should be:

```
    addFieldError("userName", "Enter UserName");
```

Use the 'name' attribute of the element ont the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simple theme in your struts tag textfield .`<s:textfield theme="simple" />` then remove it.
Normally error Message gets sandwitched between two rows. Try This.
And give me your reply.

Comment: if any body have any solution to my above problem then please help!